# Parameters coming from nowhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, parameters

```
var streams = require('stream');
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(JSONObjectStream, streams.Transform);

function JSONObjectStream(opt){
    streams.Transform.call(this, opt);
}

JSONObjectStream.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, callback){
    object = data ? JSON.parse(data.toString()) : "";
    this.emit("object", object);
    object.handled = true;
    this.push(JSON.stringify(object));
    callback();
};

JSONObjectStream.prototype._flush = function(cb){
    cb();
};

var tc = new JSONObjectStream();

tc.on("object", function(object){
    console.log("Name: %s", object.name);
    console.log("Color: %s", object.color);
});

tc.on("data", function(data){
    console.log("Data: %s", data.toString());
});

tc.write('{"name": "Carolinus", "color": "Green"}');
tc.write('{"name": "Solarius", "color": "Blue"}');
```

I have a bunch questions about the code above. I've tested it out, and it does work perfectly.

First question: 
     How does the "opt" parameter get its value in the function JSONObjectStream(opt)? I do not see any value being passed when I create the "tc" object.

Second Question: 
     When I prototype the transform method, from where does the "callback" parameter receive its value? I do not see a value being passed to it when I call the method with tc.write().

Third Question:
     What is the flush() method's use in this program? I do not see it being called anywhere in the code. And if it is called somewhere, from where its "cb" parameter receive its value?

Fourth Question: 
     How is the variable "object" able to be declared? It doesn't has neither a var nor a this before it.

I got this code from a book, but I can't figure out how it works.

Thanks for taking your time to check it out!

Comment: For your first question, the value of `opt` would be `undefined`, because as you say you call the function without passing a value.

Comment: So what is the point of having it there in the first place?

Comment: From its name, I would guess `opt` is intended to hold some options that would then, if provided, get used by `streams.Transform`. If the code works without it then presumably those options are optional.

Comment: 1) It doesn't. `opt` is `undefined` since you are not passing a value. 2) `_transform` gets its arguments from the code that calls it. 4) `object` is a parameter: `function(object) {}`.

Comment: @FelixKling For my 4th question, I'm talking about the declaration of object in the transform method prototype.

Comment: Ah... if you assign to an undeclared variable, JavaScript creates it for you - in global scope. It's bad practice, always use `var`.

Comment: Also. But _transform is only getting one argument when it is called. So I don't know what the callback is.

Comment: What makes you think it only gets one argument?